# Problems in developing a realtime app just like whatsapp

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I want to create a real-time app in Flutter just like WhatsApp. But, I don't know how to do backend coding (Firebase) which will ensure private messaging among users who will get registered in that app?

Is there any tutorial which covers my this question, please?

Comment: Hey Qalb, I know this is annoying but this is not the type of questions you should be asking here. StackOverflow is for specific coding problems which you are tackling. Please read the guidelines here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Answering how to create a backend like Whatsapp is a whole book not one answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase offers two solutions when it comes to backend databases.

1) Realtime Database - Firebase's original database implementation. It uses a nosql data structure to send and receive data in realtime. The data is based on a large json tree-like structure that connected clients can read and write to (with sufficient permissions). In my opinion this solution offers a lightweight structure for simple datatypes and minimal data.

2) Cloud Firestore - Firebase's newest database implementation. Also uses a nosql data structure, but rather than one large JSON tree it uses a collections and documents structure, where one collection can have many documents. In my opinion this solution scales much better for easy to view hierarchical data

**Database Summary**

Realtime Database stores all data in a large json tree and Cloud Firestore stores data in a Collection/Document structure (under the hood it is very similar to json anyway). New projects are recommended to start using Cloud Firestore whilst legacy projects are fine to continue to use the Realtime Database.

There is a summary of both solutions here
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore

**Instant Messaging App**

You could define a Cloud Firestore database with a Collection called 'messages' which will hold many documents. Each document holds a few data types such as 
- Message (e.g 'hello!')
- Sender (e.g. 'test@gmail.com')
- Timestamp (e.g. 'May 18, 2020 at 3:08:52 PM UTC+1')

So the database would look something like (using json to show the relationships)

```
{
    "messages": {
        "document1": [
            {
                "message": "Hello!"
            },
            {
                "sender": "test@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                "timestamp": "May 18, 2020 at 4:00:00 PM UTC+1"
            }
        ],
        "document2": [
            {
                "message": "Hi test!"
            },
            {
                "sender": "jim@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                "timestamp": "May 18, 2020 at 4:01:00 PM UTC+1"
            }
        ]
        ....
    }
}
```

**Authentication**

Cloud Firestore has many different sign in methods, to start out with you could simply implement 'Email/password' this allows the clients to sign up with their credentials and in Cloud Firestore will associate a user id with the user. The user id can then be used within the database rules to only allow authenticated users to read and write from the database (this can be further customised). An example database rule would look like

```
// Allow read/write access on all documents to any user signed in to the application
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Firebase provide documentation regarding the data model here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot clone whatsapp articles or projects, thanks to google you can check some:

https://medium.com/quick-code/creating-whatsapp-clone-using-firebase-f7971f32b35
https://github.com/pauek/whatsapp-firebase
https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-a-chat-app-with-flutter-and-firebase-from-scratch-9eaa7f41782e